# Loading json data and bind it to custome layout

Tags: java, android, json

I am new on the android programming and I have an issue .I am getting from [thislink](http://api.piyasa.com/json/?kaynak=doviz_guncel_serb) Json data and load those data to my custom listview,but when loading I t crashed.
errors is soemthing like these:parse result error,and http connection error.

here is the my main.java,

```
package com.example.dovizkuru;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class AnaEkran  extends Activity{
     public static final String URL = "http://api.piyasa.com/json/?kaynak=doviz_guncel_serb";  

     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle skr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(skr);
        setContentView(R.layout.anaekran);

        JSONObject json =getJSONfromURL(URL);       

       UyarıGoster("String mesaj");
        //Loop the Array
        try{    
        JSONArray  kurlar = json.getJSONArray("");
        for(int i=0;i < kurlar.length();i++){                       

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = kurlar.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("foexid",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("foex", "Ad : " + e.getString("foex"));
            map.put("buy", "Alış : " + e.getString("buy"));
            map.put("sell", "Satış : " +  e.getString("sell"));
            mylist.add(map);
    }
        }
       catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
       }


         SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
             mylist, R.layout.mymain,new String[] { "foex", "buy","sell" },
             new int[] {R.id.foex,R.id.tvParaAlis,R.id.tvParaSatis });

             ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            // Setting the adapter to the listView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}



        private   void  UyarıGoster(String mesaj){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    mesaj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();


            }


     public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is){
            //burada gelen veriyi string değerine çevireceğiz
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                String line = null; 
                try { 
                  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                      sb.append(line).append("\n"); 
                  } 
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                } finally { 
                  try { 
                      is.close(); 
                  } catch (IOException e) { 
                  } 
                } 
                return sb.toString(); 
            }









     public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

            //initialize
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONObject jArray = null;

            //http post
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }

            //convert response to string
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }

            //try parse the string to a JSON object
            try{
                    jArray = new JSONObject(result);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }

            return jArray;
        } 


}
```

error  datails here

```
02-16 16:52:49.141: E/Trace(13341): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-16 16:52:55.011: E/log_tag(13341): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-16 16:52:55.011: E/log_tag(13341): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 16:52:55.031: E/log_tag(13341): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-16 16:52:55.401: W/dalvikvm(13341): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f91438)
```

Comment: `errors is soemthing like these:parse result error,and http connection error.` Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** is coming because you parsing your Json in main thread. Try to use Asnync Class for that. If you don't want to use Async class than paste this code in your onCreate.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 }
```

Comment: it tells me no permmison internet !?

Comment: You have to include internet permission in manifest . u did that ?   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: 02-16 17:33:44.341: E/log_tag(21527): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"time":"17:30","foex":"USD","sell":"2.1800","buy":"2.1790","change":"0.000"},0.252"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-16 17:33:44.341: W/dalvikvm(21527): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f91438)

Comment: Please recheck your parsing it clearly showing that you are taking JsonArray as JsonObject.

Comment: yes u are right,I was getting the values as a array like this [].so that It gave the error.to fix the problem first convert it to jsonobject like this ,String json =getJSONfromURL(URL);  
  String ss= json.toString();
     ss="{ 'data':"+ss+"}";
 and fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of All Call the Json From URL using AsyncTask in BackGround check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  link ,what you are doing is calling from Main Thread Which is wrong that's why you are getting **NETWORK ON MAIN THREAD EXCEPTION** i guess this is the main cause for your app to get crashed.